# How to handle Combining Diacritical Marks with UnicodeUtils?

Tags: ruby, unicode, diacritics, unicode-normalization, phonetics

I am trying to insert spaces into a string of IPA characters, e.g. to turn `ɔ̃wɔ̃tɨ`  into `ɔ̃ w ɔ̃ t ɨ`. Using split/join was my first thought:

```
s = ɔ̃w̃ɔtɨ
s.split('').join(' ') #=> ̃ ɔ w ̃ ɔ p t ɨ
```

As I discovered by examining the results, letters with diacritics are in fact encoded as two characters. After some research I found the UnicodeUtils module, and used the each_grapheme method:

```
UnicodeUtils.each_grapheme(s) {|g| g + ' '} #=> ɔ ̃w ̃ɔ p t ɨ
```

This worked fine, except for the inverted breve mark. The code changes `̑a` into `̑ a`. I tried normalization (`UnicodeUtils.nfc`, `UnicodeUtils.nfd`), but to no avail. I don't know why the `each_grapheme` method has a problem with this particular diacritic mark, but I noticed that in gedit, the breve is also treated as a separate character, as opposed to tildes, accents etc. So my question is as follows: is there a straightforward method of normalization, i.e. turning the combination of `Latin Small Letter A` and `Combining Inverted Breve` into `Latin Small Letter A With Inverted Breve`?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right ȃ? I have no experience with these characters but copied the one from [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_breve) with Unicode +U0203 and when I ran `puts UnicodeUtils.each_grapheme("ɔ̃ȃɨ").to_a.join(' ')` it did output `"ɔ̃ ȃ ɨ"` correctly.

Comment: In fact, I am sure I use the wrong ȃ. I read input data from a file and have no control over its content. I would like to replace all occurences of ȃ (U+0311 + U+0061) with correct version (U+0203). Maybe it is possible to do it in the text editor, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can replace it as follows: `"̑a".gsub("\u0311\u0061", "\u0203")`. The `"̑a"` at the start is the one made up from U+0311 and U+0061. The `gsub` will replace it with the single character, proper version (technically you can use `sub` but if you want to replace all occurrences in a larger text, use `gsub`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I found more "standalone" diacritic marks in the text. There were too many combinations to use gsub, so I decided to simply remove all [Combining Diacritical Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks_(Unicode_block)). It is a rather lame workaround (and I lost some phonetic information), but I cannot think of anything better. Maybe there is a way to check whether a character is a combining one?

Comment: Note the combining character should be _after_ the base character. In your question you say `̑a` is transformed into `̑ a`, but the character should appear as `ȃ`, so I suspect your example has the combining mark _before_ the base character, which would explain the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question concerns Ruby but I suppose the problem is about the same as with Python. A simple solution is to test the combining diacritical marks explicitly :

```
import unicodedata
liste=[]
s = u"ɔ̃w̃ɔtɨ"
comb=False
prec=u""
for char in s:
    if unicodedata.combining(char):
        liste.append(prec+char)
        prec=""
    else:
        liste.append(prec)
        prec=char
liste.append(prec)
print " ".join(liste)
>>>>  ɔ̃  w̃  ɔ t ɨ
```